# Django jquery AJAX form submission in view and display results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-forms

There are a lot of different posts about all parts of this, I just can't quite figure out how it all fits together.

I have `name` that is displayed with an `update button` next to it. When the `update button` is clicked it shows a `form` to update the `name`. In the `form` is a `save changes button`. When the changes are saved, it should reload the `name` at the top, and should the `update button` be clicked again, the `form` should show the `new name` info.

urls.py

```
path('profile/<int:pk>/', views.customer_profile, name='profile'),
path('update-profile/<int:pk>/', views.update_profile, name='update-profile'),
```

views.py

```
def customer_profile(request, pk):
    name = get_object_or_404(CEName, id=pk)
    name_form = NameForm(instance=name)
    return render(
        request,
        'customer/customer_profile.html',
        {'name':name, 'NameForm': name_form}
    )


def update_profile(request, pk):
    if request.POST:
        name_form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if name_form.is_valid():
            name_form.save()
    name = get_object_or_404(CEName, id=pk)
    context = {'name':name, 'NameForm': name_form}
    html = render_to_string('customer/customer_profile.html', context)
    return HttpResponse(html, content_type="application/json")
```

template.html

```
<div id="name" class="container d-flex justify-content-between pt-1">
    {{ name }}
    <button id="update_button" class="bold btn btn-main btn-sm button-main">UPDATE</button>
  </div>
  <div id="div_NameForm" class="container" style="display: none;">
    <hr size="3px">
    <form id="NameForm" method="POST" data-url-name="{% url 'customer:update-profile' name.id %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ NameForm.as_p }}
      <br>
    <button type="submit" id="save_changes" class="btn btn-main button-main btn-block">Save Changes</button>
    </form>
  </div>
<script src="{% static 'ce_profiles/ce_profiles_jquery.js' %}"></script>
```

jquery.js

```
$('#save_changes').click(function() {
  var NameForm = $('#NameForm');
  $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: NameForm.attr('data-url-name'),
      data: NameForm.serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#name').html(data); 
      }
    });
});
```

The code for the `update button` toggle is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery, to start with.
- First, you could (some may say *should*) have put a `submit` event handler on the on the *form* instead of a `click` event for *button*.
- Second, you are doing an AJAX call so you should prevent form submission using `.preventDefault()` on the *submit event* that was trigged when the button was pressed. This will prevent the page from reloading.
- Third, in your ajax success callback you should use `text()` instead of `html()` since `name` I imagine is text and not html, however that's just an assumption.

```
$('#NameForm').on('submit', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var NameForm = $('#NameForm');
  $.ajax({
      ...
      success: function(response) {
          $(#name).text(response); // or response.name or whatever
      }
  });
})
```